# Laravel 5.4: Re-assign a soft-deleted record

Tags: laravel, soft-delete

Using soft-deletes in Laravel 5.4.  When I try to create an record that already has been created but soft-deleted I get the message "The xxx has already been taken".  What is the best way to be able handle the event when 
a user attempts to save a record that has already has been soft deleted?

I have been trying to capture this event in the store method of the controller but the store method does not get called if the record already exists - AFAIK.

In my use case I have radios that can be associated to only one user at a time but can be unassigned e.g. soft-deleted and then reassigned to another user in the future.

Comment: check if the record exist , if no = store , if yes = check if soft-deleted , if no = the record is assigned , if yes = updated assginment(not store)(remove soft-delete)

Answer (score 0):

You can `restore()` to restore a soft deleted model:

```
App\User::withTrashed()->where('id', $user_id)->restore();
```

[Restoring Soft Deleted Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael.  Do you know why I am not seeing the "store" method get called when a record already exists in the table but is soft-deleted / trashed?

Comment: Did you do validation before you saved the model?